# ArcGIS Pro / arcpy "Polygon To Raster": wrong output for only one of multiple DXF-polygon-files

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

Multiple 3D triangle meshes are produced in a modeling software and exported as DXF-files with the same workflow. The polygons of the DXF-files are used in **ArcGIS Pro 3.1.0** to generate raster with `Polygon To Raster` with the same parameters. However, one of the polygons generates a raster whose output is obviously wrong. The procedure is as summarized in the bullet list below. The bold letters in the square brackets refer to the notations in the images below. The file `dxfpolygonfile01` is representative for multiple other DXF-files for which the process works fine. Only the file `dxfpolygonfile02` causes the problem.

- [**A**] The two polygon files `dxfpolygonfile01` (*green*) and `dxfpolygonfile02` (*red*) consist of triangles with Z-values assigned to their corners (for **P** see [**F**] below).
- [**B**] `Polygon To Raster` with settings described in [**C**]-[**F**] generates a correct raster `raster01` for `dxfpolygonfile01` (*green*) and a wrong `raster02` for `dxfpolygonfile02` (*red*). The error is expressed in content (value) and in extension of `raster02`.

  - [**C**] The DXF-files `dxfpolygonfile01` and `dxfpolygonfile02` are equally configured as they both result from the same production and export process.
  - [**D**] Equal parameters are chosen for `Polygon To Raster` to produce `raster01` and `raster02`.
  - [**E**] Standard input parameters are left for the `Environments` for `Polygon To Raster` in both cases.
  - [**F**] A check with the `Explore`-function at any arbitrary location covered by both datasets (e.g. P in [**A**]) reveals correct value for `raster01` (*green rectangles*) and wrong value for `raster02` (*red rectangles*).

The same occurs with `arcpy.PolygonToRaster_conversion` in `arcpy` and on another computer.

I assume that there is a problem with the `Environments` as it happens to the DXF-file with the largest extent. However, increasing the `Processing Extent` beyond the polygons' extension does not change the output.

Does anybody identify the cause of the wrong output for `raster02`?

[image: polygon & raster]
[image: setting]

Comment: Use repair geometry, modeling software frequently produce wrong vertices order in polygons. Might even have negative, according to arcgis, area.

Comment: It has solved the problem. Please write a full answer so I can accept it as solution.

Comment: I already did , same issue, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333981/gaps-in-polygon-after-merging#333984 so self-answer please

Comment: See if this is relevant as well https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/455118/is-arcmap-reading-shapefiles-table-correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is similar to the case [Gaps in polygon after merging](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333981/gaps-in-polygon-after-merging#333984). It can get solved as suggested by `FelixIP` in the comments: apply [`Repair Geometry (Data Management)`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/repair-geometry.htm).